# I want to know where the values for the given dropdown is stored in Database for magento currency

Tags: php, magento

I want to know where the values for the given dropdown is stored in Database for
    magento currency
    the code is for displaying the dropdown for magento currency.

```
<select id="currency_options_allow" class=" select multiselect" multiple="multiple"   
size="10" name="groups[options][fields][allow][value][]">

<option value="AFN">Afghan Afghani</option>
<option value="ALL">Albanian Lek</option>
<option value="DZD">Algerian Dinar</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to know where the data gets saved once you store the currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of currencies belongs to the locale settings and can be found in  /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml